# Debugging issue with VS 2022 and .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui, visual-studio-2022

Debugging the application ANDROID MAUI does not work correctly.

When I add breakpoints in the code and run debugging in my android app, I always get the following exception: "No compatible code running on the thread".

I have tried:

1. Deactivate the hot reload
2. Disable "Debug Your Code Only" in Options
3. Reinstall VS 2022
4. Reinstall MAUI

But I get always the same error.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is a preview version of *.net* and *visual studio*, if you have a bug you should report it through the appropriate channels, so the developers can fix it

Comment: The same happens to me, what I usually do is write some `Console.WriteLine` to debug the application

Comment: Side note: Even though that .NET MAUI will be released next year (2022), next week VS2022 is released. We'll see by then

Comment: Any update on this issue? Debugging with Console.WriteLine gets old real quick

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 on version 17.6.3 and this issue haven't fixed yet

Comment: VS 17.6.4 and this is still an issue

Comment: Hello, did you find out how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue with Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.5.  After upgrading to version 17.7.6 (current at time of writing) the issue vanished.

Comment: I can confirm this was the case for me too. I went from version 17.6.4 to 17.7.7 and the issue went away. Thanks for this. +1